# Virtual machine static ip doesnt work

Tags: linux, ubuntu, virtual-machines

I have created vps private Ubuntu server on virtual machine.
Then I have deploy my app on it with static ip 192.168.56.101.
Everything is working,  when I open it on my local machine,  but when I try to access it with my mobile phone browser,  it doesn't load .
What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Is your phone using that specific network? 192.168.anything is a private range.